# CircleCI or Gitlab equivalents of Azure Pipelines parameters?

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops, circleci, cicd

So Azure Pipelines have this parameters system where you can manually input them and run pipeline
[image]

Does CircleCI or Gitlab offer something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CircleCI does. You can refer to [their documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/triggers-overview#run-a-pipeline-from-the-circleci-web-app).

I don't know enough about GitLab, though.

Comment: Circling back on this one... In GitLab, you can also [run a pipeline manually and set specific variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines) required for the pipeline to run. The link is for the GitLab EE but I just checked in GitLab cloud, and it's the same.